# How to remove padding from b-dropdown-item

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to get more space available in b-dropdown-item. It seems that there is a button with allot of padding and i would like to remove it.

I have tried making a css class like this, but it did not solve the issue.

```
 .removePadding > button{
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit

HTML

[image]

VUE HTML
[image]

I found a solution, change the property when mounting component.

```
fixPadding(id){
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
 
  element.style.padding = '0px'
},
```

Still would be nice if i could do with css

Comment: Could you reproduce your code into a snippet please?

Comment: It's hard to say without the code, but try targeting '.removePadding' instead of '.removePadding > button'. And try with !important too, just in case anything else is overriding this style

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!important`

If that doesn't work try one of the following (with and without `!important`):

```
padding: 0px 0px 0px;

padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
```

If none of them work, post the HTML to see if the problem could be that you are targeting the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

you try to remove the padding for buttons but you don't write the selector in right way

```
.removePadding ul > li a{
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

try this way